# Jquery tabs: autoHeight for expanding content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery sliding tabs from this [SITE](http://codecanyon.net/item/sliding-tabs-jquery-plugin/full_screen_preview/141774), which work very nice. The only problem is that the autoHeight jquery function does not adjust to expanding content. *Rephrase:* The tab container will ajust to the height of the inactive content but the issue is that once the content inside container becomes active and expands vertically it will no longer fit and not be seen <--- It fails to adjust to that. Here is the example [JSFFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HZj7k/10/)

**I try doing this to adjust the height to expanding content but it is not working:**

```
<script>
 var height = 50 // Set to the height you want
        $('.st_view').css('height', height+'px')

    });​

    </script>
```

**Overall Jquery**

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('div#st_horizontal').slideTabs({
            // Options              
            contentAnim: 'slideH',
            autoHeight: true,
            contentAnimTime: 600,
            contentEasing: 'easeInOutExpo',
            tabsAnimTime: 300
        });

        var height = 50 // Set to the height you want
        $('.st_view').css('height', height+'px')

    });​

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only togglers that cause the content to expand, you can modify your toggler code like this:

```
$('#title').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#content').toggle();
    var $tab = $(this).closest('.st_tab_view');
    $tab.closest('.st_view').css('height', $tab.height());
});
```

For a more general solution, get the [jQuery resize plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/), and add this code:

```
$('.st_tab_view').resize(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.st_view').css('height', $this.height());
});
```

Comment: Your answer was superb, I only have one little issue when using the plugin and the code you provided above. The issue is that it re-sizes the first tab to the tallest tab there is, after that everything else is working fine. Here is my [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/slidingtabs/horizontal.html)